# Asks for a text and then iterate over the letters in a specific manner

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, slice

I'm trying to solve a problem I have that requires arrays and loops.

The task is just to take a random string and write out all the letters so that it looks like this:
R, Ra, Ran, Rand ,Rando , Random, RandomS, RandomSt, RandomStr, RandomStri, RandomStrin, RandomString.

I solved that part like this:

```js
function sometext() {
  var temptext = document.getElementById("textinput").value;
  var temparray = [];
  temparray = temptext.slice();

  for (var i = 0; i <= temparray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("printit").innerHTML += temparray.slice(0, i) + "<br/>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="textinput" onchange="sometext()">
<div id="printit"></div>
```

The code runs that string that it gets from an inputbox that anyone writes in.

The next step is to have this string remove the first letter and then write it out like above so it would look like this: a, an, and, ando, andom, andomS, andomSt, andomStr, andomStri, andomStrin, andomString and then remove the first letter again so the output would be: n, nd, ndo, ndom, ndomS, ndomSt, ndomStr, ndomStri, ndomStrin, ndomString and so on until it runs out of letters to remove from. I don't know how to make it work for any amount of letters.

Example output

```
R
Ra
Ran
Rand
Rando
Random
a
an
and
ando
andom
n
nd
ndo
ndom
d
do
dom
o
om
m
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like you need to create a new loop that contains the current loop, add a `.splice()` to modify the string and run it again until complete.

Comment: I have a solution that works for a certain amount of characters but the issue with that answer is that it's just that loop with if-statements that says if i == temparray.length it will start the loop on the next character or when i = 1, and repeating the loop starting with i =1 and then when that i == temparray.length it starts from i= 2 so you get a solution but its just a lot of code and it doesn't look good.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly how it should look like, thanks alot!

Comment: also, I'm not sure how to implement that loop @coll, I'm quite new with JavaScript

Comment: Try to build it first, stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Share your attempt.

Comment: @coll OP tried and did the first part. It is not a trivial thing. The question has enough information and a [mcve] to give an answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about a map and shift

```js
const output = document.getElementById("printit");

function sometext(fld) {
  let temptext = [...fld.value]; // or fld.value.split("")
  const arr = []
  while (temptext.length > 0) {
    arr.push(
      temptext.map((_, i) => temptext.slice(0, i + 1).join("")).join("<br>")
    )
    temptext.shift(); // drop first letter
  }
  output.innerHTML = arr.join("<br/>")
}
```

```html
<input id="textinput" oninput="sometext(this)">
<div id="printit"></div>
```

Comment: I think I explained it poorly, So for a string like Hello, the code I'm trying to make would make the output like this: H, He, Hel, Hell, Hello , e, el, ell, ello , l, ll, llo , l, lo , o so it removes the first character of every loop-iteration and writes out all parts, starting on the first character available , so I appreciate your help but not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok solved it for you. Not trivial

Comment: While some might understand that using the "Enter" key fires the "change" event, I think it would be useful to include that instruction in your answer for those who try to test the snippet. (On the surface, it's a rather obscure cause-effect.)

Comment: @jsejcksn Changed to the input event

Comment: This answers it for sure, I just need to sit with it for a while since it has some new concepts I'm not familiar with yet.  I did post my not so elegant solution earlier if anyone wants to give some input, not necessary but if you want to see how I "solved" it, it's there.

Comment: Only thing I added was a while and a shift.

Answer (score 1):

When you get array with all needed values, just iterate through and print it as you want or to html or to console

```js
const text = 'Random';


const result = [...text].flatMap((ch, index) => {
  const righPart = text.slice(index, text.length);
  const leftParts = [...righPart].map((ch, index) => righPart.slice(0, index + 1))
  return leftParts;
});


console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

**Update**

It just combination of two similar functions

First return array with only right parts of string:

```
const text = 'Random'
[...text].map((ch, index) => text.slice(index, text.length))
// ['Random', 'andom', 'ndom', 'dom', 'om', 'm']
```

Second is similar and returns only left parts:

```
const text = 'Random'
[...text].map((ch, index) => text.slice(0, index + 1))
// ['R', 'Ra', 'Ran', 'Rand', 'Rando', 'Random']
```

In solution I use `.flatMap()` to make result array flatten. That's all.

Comment: Elegant code. Very hard to understand. Can you break it down for us?

Comment: @mplungjan See `--- update---` section with some explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        function sometext() {
            var temptext = document.getElementById("textinput").value;
            var temparray = [];
            temparray = temptext.slice();
            for (var i = 0; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(0, i) + "<br/>";

                if (i == temparray.length) 
                    {
                        for (var i = 1; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                        {
                            document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(1, i) + "<br/>";

                        if (i == temparray.length) 
                            {
                                for (var i = 2; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                                {
                                    document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(2, i) + "<br/>";

                                    if (i == temparray.length) 
                                    {
                                        for (var i = 3; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                                            document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(3, i) + "<br/>";

                                            if (i == temparray.length) 
                                                {
                                                for (var i = 4; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                                                    {
                                                    document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(4, i) + "<br/>";

                                                    if (i == temparray.length) 
                                                        {
                                                        for (var i = 5; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                                                            {
                                                            document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(5, i) + "<br/>";

                                                            if (i == temparray.length) 
                                                                {
                                                                for (var i = 6; i <= temparray.length; i++) 
                                                                {
                                                                document.getElementById("printout").innerHTML += temparray.slice(6, i) + "<br/>";
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
               }
        
    </script>
   <p><input type="text" id="textinput" value=""></p>
    <p><input type="button" value="Check it out" onclick="sometext()">
    </p>
    <div id="printout"></div>
```

I'm showing how I first answered it, it runs a loop and prints out the first iteration, then when i == temparray.length it starts on a new loop with i starting on the next number and prints out the next iteration and when it reaches the length of the array it starts again with the next number and this process continues for 6 iterations. Now this doesn't look very nice since it's not a generalized solution, and that's what I'm trying to figure out but with no success. As the code is now, it  does it for 6 character words, in order to make it for 7 characters I just need to add another if (i == temparray.length) and for (var i = [previousNumber +1]; i< temparray.length; i++) and then write it out on the div element. It works but it isn't very pretty in my opinion.